# How do you include twitter bootstrap with spring mvc?

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have spring mvc supplied text boxes and buttons in form page how to include twitter bootstrap in those tags. Where do I place bootstrap related files in the folder structure and which jar do I required to use bootstrap?

Example text boxes are:

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>               
 <form:form method="post" commandName="stdcmd">
 username:<form:form path="txtUname">
 password:<form:form path="txtPwd"> 
 <input type="submit" value="register"/>
 </form:form>
```

Comment: I understand your question as that you need to apply bootstrap styles to your application. If this is the case then it needs to placed under your web folder and include the css into your jsp.

Comment: not working @Pradeep Sekar

Comment: what is not working? You need to call the bootstrap classes in your input/form tag etc.

Answer (score 0):

To use the bootstrap, you need to place the bootstrap files in the web folder. For example, resources/bootstrap folder.  Then add the link to those files in jsp like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also on your spring config file include this one:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/bootstrap
```

[Check this link for more info](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

You should be able to access the classes from bootstrap and apply in your jsp.